# Android webview - page not found

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, webview, twitter-bootstrap-3, http-status-code-404

I have an android application with a WebView.
When I load the following URL in the Dolphin browser, it loads fine:

http://www.insites-m.com/articals/test/index.html

But when I load it into my WebView I'm getting error 404 - Page Not Found.
I think it somehow related to bootstrap support.
It opened good only in Dolphin browser, in the built-in internet application on my device it also give me the 404 error.

Here is my WebView definitions:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.snapWebView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);




    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }




    });

    WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            return true;

        }
    };

    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.insites-m.com/articals/test/index.html")
```

Here is my manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

BTW - The page was created using:
https://www.easel.io/

Thanks.

Comment: Did you give INTERNET permission in manifest?

Comment: Where is your `webview.loadUrl()` method ?

Comment: Yes.
I can access to other web sites.

Comment: @Spring Breaker: Forgot to write it on the question. But it exist in my code right after the web clients creation, in the onCreate method:
webView.loadUrl("http://www.insites-m.com/articals/test/index.html")

Comment: Here is my manifest:

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: There is no webview.loadUrl() method in your code.

Comment: @pratik: I have loadUrl and the right permissions.
Question was edited. Thanks.

Comment: Just a long shot: have you tried implementing `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in case something is being called that needs to be handled there? You might just add it and use the debugger to see what might be passed to it, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

Edit

Most probably the issue is that this website has some kind of verification for android devices or devices of some resolution and shows them the error page.

I get the same in my android chrome browser
so i come to the above conclusion and the reason it shows in dolphin browser is maybe your

**dolphin browser is set to desktop mode like this http://www.guidingtech.com/assets/postimages/2012/10/Dolphin-Browser-for-Android-1.png**

i checked the code of the html
it has this line

```
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Limelight|Flamenco|Federo|Yesteryear|Josefin Sans|Spinnaker|Sansita One|Handlee|Droid Sans|Oswald:400,300,700" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheets/common.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheets/fontawesome.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheets/project.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheets/tour.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**media="screen"**

media screen — The browser identifies itself as being in the “screen” category. This roughly means the browser considers itself desktop-class — as opposed to e.g. an older mobile phone browser (note that the iPhone browsers, do identify themselves as being in the screen category).

maybe thats causing the issue,its unlikely but worth a looksy.

[image]

===========================================

Assuming, you do not have permissions set

set this in your manifest file

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It did not help :(
Still getting the 404.
@ViVekH Which browser do you use?

Comment: no offense but just to confirm ,if you load www.google.com in your webview.loadUrl it works?

Comment: :) That's OK.
Yes.
Actually, it opened just in Dolphin. In the built-in android internet app it also gives my the 404.
I think it related to bootstrap css supprt.

Comment: Can you please tell me in which (desktop) browser you got the 404. (In my chrome browser I see this link fine...)

Comment: chrome itself

most probably the issue is that this website has some kind of verification for android devices
or devices of some resolution
and shows them the error page

Comment: Its not a user agant issue.
My Dolphin set to Android agant and it show the URL just fine...

Comment: webviews use chrome client and in inbuilt android chrome the weblink you gave returns a 404 , also the 404 it shows is a custom error page not the default one webview or browsers show so the issue is from the website side.Question is why it is showing custom 404 error for android devices/chrome browser